# Wordpress editor showing weird squares

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I was just trying to edit one blog post in wordpress and I found the editor to show it's WYSIWYG options all in squares... Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Thank you for your time...

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a [classic block](https://wordpress.com/support/wordpress-editor/blocks/classic-block/) and that the characters are not displaying.

There's several things to try:

- [Install the Gutenberg plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gutenberg/), it offers a version of Gutenberg that
  is newer than what is included within WordPress by default.
- Disable all other plugins and see if you still have the error
- Find if there's [any errors in the developers console of your browser](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-your-browser-to-diagnose-javascript-errors/).